# Deleting certain files from folder in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and am trying the following:

I have 7 files in my directory.

```
MyFileName1.jpg
MyFileName2.jpg
MyFileName3.jpg
MineFileName1.jpg
MineFileName2.jpg
MineFileName3.jpg
MineFileName4.jpg
```

Based on a condition, I am trying to remove MyFileName2.jpg and MyFileName3.jpg.
Please suggest.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: But... what exactly **IS** the condition?

Comment: @Tomerikoo: I have the folder has many files. I am checking one image after another and extracting the text. The place where I get the word "Achieved", I delete all the remaining files of higher numbers. So sometimes, the file numbers (in file names) may change. Hope am making sense.

Answer (score 1):

`s.remove()`  removes a file.

`os.rmdir()`  removes an empty directory.

`shutil.rmtree()`  deletes a directory and all its contents.

Path objects from the Python 3.4+ `pathlib` module also expose these instance methods:

`pathlib.Path.unlink()` removes a file or symbolic link.

`pathlib.Path.rmdir()` removes an empty directory.
You can also use

```py
import os
os.remove("file_path/<file_name>.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('path_to_your_dir')
names = ['MyFileName2.jpg', 'MyFileName3.jpg'] # Name of files to be deleted

for file in folder.iterdir():
  if file.name in names:
    os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Thanks... But the folder has many files. I am checking one image after another. The place where I get the word "Achieved", I delete all the remaining files of higher numbers. 

So sometimes, the file numbers (in file names) may change. Hope am making sense. 

Thanks for your guidance